# How do I treat <script> tags differently in simple ANTLR lexer?

Tags: html-parsing, antlr, antlr3, lexer

I'm writing a really simple lexer for doing syntax highlighting of arbitrary text, one of which is HTML. The goal of the lexer is just to provide a flat stream of tokens.

I started with the [XML tutorial](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/1.+Lexer) on the Antlr3 website, but am having some trouble with script tags.

An example of the HTML which causes this problem:

`<head>
  <script>alert(2 < 3);</script>
</head>`

And the grammar..

```
@members {
    boolean inTag = false;
}

TAG_START_OPEN : '<'
                 { inTag = true; } ;
TAG_END_OPEN : '</'
               { inTag = true; } ;

TAG_CLOSE : { inTag }?=> '>' { inTag = false; } ;
TAG_SELF_CLOSE : { inTag }?=> '/>' { inTag = false; } ;
PCDATA : { !inTag }?=> (~'<')+ ;

// ...
```

The problem is that the lexer gets confused when seeing the '<' tag within the Javascript code and thinks it is a close tag. I guess the goal would be for the lexer to use lookahead to determine whether a '<' is proceeded by '/script>' if the open tag was a script tag, however I'm unsure of how to do this nicely with ANTLR.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick demo of how you could accomplish this:

```java
grammar T;

options {
  output=AST;
}

tokens {
  DATA;
  ATTRIBUTES;
  ATTRIBUTE;
  ATOMS;
}

@lexer::members {
  private boolean inTag = false;
  private boolean isScript = false;

  private boolean ahead(String s) {
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
      int ch = input.LA(i + 1);
      if(ch != s.charAt(i)) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}

parse
 : tag EOF -> tag
 ;

tag
 : TagOpen attributes TagOpenEnd atoms TagClose -> ^(TagOpen attributes atoms)
 ;

attributes
 : attribute* -> ^(ATTRIBUTES attribute*)
 ;

attribute
 : Key Assign Value -> ^(ATTRIBUTE Key Value)
 ;

atoms
 : atom* -> ^(ATOMS atom*)
 ;

atom
 : PCData
 | ScriptData
 | tag
 ;

TagOpen
 : '<' Name 
   {
     inTag=true; 
     isScript = $Name.text.equals("script");
     setText($Name.text);
   }
 ;

TagClose
 : {!inTag}?=> '</' Name '>' 
   {
     isScript = false;
     setText($Name.text);
   }
 ;

TagOpenEnd
 : {inTag}?=> '>' {inTag=false;}
 ;

Key
 : {inTag}?=> Name
 ;

Assign
 : {inTag}?=> '='
 ;

Value
 : {inTag}?=> '"' ~'"'* '"'
   {
     setText($text.substring(1, $text.length() - 1));
   }
 ;

PCData
 : {!inTag && !isScript}?=> ~'<'+
   {
     if($text.trim().isEmpty()) {
       skip();
     }
   }
 ;

ScriptData
 : {!inTag && isScript}?=> ({!ahead("</script>")}?=> . )+
 ;

Space
 : {inTag}?=> (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')+ {skip();}
 ;

fragment Name : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+;
```

If I now parse the input:

```html
<head>
  <script> alert(2 < 3); </script> 
  <span key="some value" x="<>">
    Mu <em>foo</em> bar!
  </span>
</head>
```

the following AST will be created by the generated parser:

[image]